# Unit Test fails to run on solution based on Helix Visual Studio Templates

Tags: unit-testing

my project solution is based on Sitecore Helix Visual Studio Templates by Ander's Laub. Im trying to write Unit tests using XUnit, but none of the tests are running and not even failing.

For test projects, I have tried using Project based on Class Library(.NET Framework), Projects based on Sitecore Helix Visual Studio Templates by Ander's Laub.

Packages used:

1. XUnit(2.4.1)
2. XUnit.Runner.VisualStudio(2.4.3)
3. XUnit.Runner.Console(2.4.1)

Framework: .NET 4.8

Visual Studio 2019: v16.8.5

**The output im getting:**

[image]

DemoTests.cs

```
public class DemoTests
    {

        [Fact]
        public void DemoTestForPassingOnly()
        {
            double expected = 5;
            double actual = 4;
            Assert.Equal(expected, actual);
        }

     }
```

Test Run Output window:

```
ProjectData: Could not find project with GUID 09fe023c-998c-4a4c-a896-bc27884e7aaf
ProjectData: Could not find project with GUID 09fe023c-998c-4a4c-a896-bc27884e7aaf
---------- Starting test run ----------
[xUnit.net 00:00:00.00] xUnit.net VSTest Adapter v2.4.3+1b45f5407b (64-bit Desktop .NET 4.0.30319.42000)
No test matches the given testcase filter `FullyQualifiedName=Linde.Foundation.SitecoreExtensions.Tests.DemoTests.DemoTestForPassingOnly` in C:\SourceTree\lindemh-sitecore\bin\Debug\Linde.Foundation.SitecoreExtensions.Tests.dll
========== Test run finished: 0 Tests run in 1.3 sec (0 Passed, 0 Failed, 0 Skipped) ==========
```

I have tried building a separate Console Application with Tests project to make sure whether this is a Visual Studio Issue, but it is running/failing/passing inside the console application, but not inside the Sitecore Project.

Do I have to configure the solution differently in order for the Tests to run successfully?

Comment: I'm guessing you tried clicking the play button in the test explorer there?

Comment: Can you verify what versions have you used for the XUnit.runer nuget packages?

Comment: @Cristi : added in the question description.

Comment: @Richard Yes tried both of the buttons.

Comment: Would you mind adding screenshot of output window after you have done rebuild solution, also check that window after you have pressed Run Test button as this window does not provide enough information.

Comment: There can be various reasons for why the tests aren't running, can you take a look at the Tests output window to see what errors you are receiving? Have you also tried creating a new Project and see if a simple unit test is running there?

Comment: I have added the contents of the output window and updated the question.

Comment: Do you have [Fact] added on each of your unittests? And also can you try to see what option you have in Visual Studio Test -> Test Settings -> Processor Architecture for AnyCPU Project?

Comment: @Cristi, added the class file.

Comment: Also I have tested this with Processor Architecture for any as well as x64

Comment: have you tried using XUnit.Runner.VisualStudio version 2.4.1.

Comment: Hi Jean, yes I have reinstalled 2.4.1 to check whether that works, the output is still the same.

Comment: You should also verify the target framework set on the unitTest project build properties aswell as the Platform target, I have 4.7.2 and the same xunit versions and it is working fine.

Comment: For my solution, the target framework has been set to 4.8 and I have verified it in the Tests projects also. I tried creating a new blank solution with Sitecore Helix Templates by Anders laub, same issues Im facing. Is there any extra configuration that is needed for the Tests project to run inside Helix solution? I could find anything in Google regarding this.
@Cristi

Comment: There aren't any extra configuration required for Test project in Helix solutions. I am using  xunit 2.4.1 with its dependencies and xunitrunner.visualstudio 2.4.3, nsubstitute, sitecore.fakedb.. You should also check your VS extensions.

Answer (score 0):

For simple unit tests using xunit I only have those references in my package :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="xunit" version="2.4.1" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="xunit.abstractions" version="2.0.3" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="xunit.analyzers" version="0.10.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="xunit.assert" version="2.4.1" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="xunit.core" version="2.4.1" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="xunit.extensibility.core" version="2.4.1" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="xunit.extensibility.execution" version="2.4.1" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="xunit.runner.console" version="2.4.1" targetFramework="net462" developmentDependency="true" />
  <package id="xunit.runner.visualstudio" version="2.4.1" targetFramework="net462" developmentDependency="true" />
</packages>
```

So I believe the XUnit.Runner.VisualStudio(2.4.3) should be 2.4.1.

Then a simple test could look like that

```
using aProject.Foundation.Utilities.Extensions;
using Xunit;

namespace aProject.Foundation.Utilities.Tests
{
    public class ExtensionsTests
    {
        public class StringExtensionTests
        {
            [Theory]
            [InlineData("some awesome string")]
            [InlineData("  some  awesome  string  ")]
            public void Should_returnValidSlug_When_passingStringWithSpaces(string name)
            {
                Assert.Equal("some-awesome-string", name.ToSlug());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Jean, so i have checked it all the packages are installed correctly. Is this anyway related to the solution template by Anders Laub im using?

Comment: I can't tell, but I would rather check other boxes before looking that way. Can you double check this q/a : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35103781/why-is-the-visual-studio-2015-2017-2019-test-runner-not-discovering-my-xunit-v2